# How to move box without clearRect() in JS' canvas better?

Tags: javascript

everyone. I am going to develop a game like Piano Tiles in JS.
The problem I encounter is that I need to let several tiles moving which might appear in different times, it let me can't use clearRect() and then draw next position's tiles, if I do so, my multiple tiles will twinkle(because when A tiles call clearRect, B tiles will disappear, which is shouldn't happen)

**The solution I figure out** is not to use clearRect() to **clear whole screen** ,I
just clear Rectangle where I don't want, and then fillRect(its fill style is same as my background color) to fill this little empty rectangle again.

My solution can almost reach my purpose, but there still some flaws in my code. When my black tiles moving, there still are some tiny gray rectangle appear (and disappear soon).

I want to know are there any better way can I move multiple box(or rectangle) ?

PS: my background is using gradient so it probably make my problem more tough.

Following is my code:

**myTiles** store two tiles, **paintWindow function** is aim at drawing background, my solution is written in **move() function**

```
var c = document.getElementById("piano");
var context = c.getContext("2d");

startGame();
function startGame(){
  paintWindow();
  myTiles = [];
  myTiles[0] = new Block(0);
  myTiles[1] = new Block(1);
}
function paintWindow(){
  my_gradient = context.createLinearGradient(0,0,0,600);
  my_gradient.addColorStop(0,"rgba(65,234,246,0.6)");
  my_gradient.addColorStop(1,"rgba(254,74,251,0.5)");

context.fillStyle = my_gradient;
context.fillRect(0,0,300,600);

context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(72,0);
context.lineTo(72,600);
context.strokeStyle = "white";
context.stroke();

context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(148,0);
context.lineTo(148,600);
context.strokeStyle = "white";
context.stroke();

context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(226,0);
context.lineTo(226,600);
context.strokeStyle = "white";
context.stroke();

context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(0,470);
context.lineTo(300,470);
context.strokeStyle = "white";
context.stroke();
}

function Block(index){
 this.index = index;
 this.appearPos = Math.floor(Math.random()*4);

 this.width = 70;
 this.height = 120;
 this.color = "black";
  switch(this.appearPos){
    case 0:
        this.x = 0;
        this.y = 0;
        break;
    case 1:
        this.x = 75;
        this.y = 0;
        break;
    case 2:
        this.x = 152;
        this.y = 0;
        break;
    case 3:
        this.x = 228;
        this.y = 0;
        break;
}
context.fillStyle = this.color;
context.fillRect(this.x,this.y,this.width,this.height);
this.interval = setInterval(move,10,this.index);
}
function move(index){
//context.clearRect(0,0,300,600);
//paintWindow();
myTiles[index].y += 1;
context.fillStyle = "black";
context.fillRect(myTiles[index].x,myTiles[index].y,70,120);

context.clearRect(myTiles[index].x,myTiles[index].y-2,70,2);
context.fillStyle = my_gradient;
context.fillRect(myTiles[index].x,myTiles[index].y-2,70,2);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you not to create a new interval for each new block, but rather create one interval in which you update all the blocks at once. This might look something like this:

```
setInterval(moveAll,10);
function moveAll(){
    context.clearRect(0,0,c.width,c.height);

    for (var i=0;i<myTiles.length;i++){
        move(i);
    }
}
```

If you can't do that for some reason, you could also draw the tiles in a separate canvas so the background is preserved when clearing a tile:

```
<div>
    <canvas id="background" style="position:absolute;left:0;top:0;">
    <canvas id="tiles" style="position:absolute;left:0;top:0;">
</div>
```

That way the second canvas would be displayed over the first one, but the background would still be visible behind it where it is transparent.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [CSS for the gradient background](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp). See [this](https://jsfiddle.net/Reader8765/pjes0m3x/12/) fiddle. Pay attention to the CSS:

```
<style>
    #piano {
        background: linear-gradient(rgba(65,234,246,0.6), rgba(254,74,251,0.5));
    }
</style>
```

Also get rid of everything about the gradient background in your `paintWindow` function:

```
  function paintWindow() {
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(72, 0);
    context.lineTo(72, 600);
    context.strokeStyle = "white";
    context.stroke();

    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(148, 0);
    context.lineTo(148, 600);
    context.strokeStyle = "white";
    context.stroke();

    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(226, 0);
    context.lineTo(226, 600);
    context.strokeStyle = "white";
    context.stroke();

    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(0, 470);
    context.lineTo(300, 470);
    context.strokeStyle = "white";
    context.stroke();
  }
```

That's all!